# My Visual Studio program is "Copyright © Hewlett-Packard Company"

Tags: visual-studio

I have a C# program which I made in Visual Studio. When I right click on my program executable in Explorer and click `Properties>Details` it says "Copyright © Hewlett-Packard Company". To troubleshoot I then created an empty Console Application, and it has the same copyright message.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have tried some tutorials about regedit but they did not work.

Comment: What do you mean it 'is copyright'. You see some notification somewhere in the software? I assume it's not actually copyrighted?

Comment: Yes, when i right click my program and click Properties>Details it says Copyright © Hewlett-Packard Company

Comment: Perhaps you have used a library which contains HP code.

Comment: No it is just a simple program. I just tested it on an empty Console Application and it says the same.

Comment: This issue we recently observed on a project created in a HP laptop. Not sure, whether its a bug in laptop or VS2015.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the [Assembly Information dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h52t681(v=vs.100).aspx) in your project properties.

In Solution Explorer you can right click on your project and select Properties. An Assembly Information button is in the Application tab.

[image: Assembly Information dialog]

I haven't tried this, but to change the default value, use regedit to modify
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOrganization`
`HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\RegisteredOrganization` (x64 systems)
[image: RegisteredOrganization]

Comment: This just modifies assembly.info

Answer (score 9):

The answer by @Louis is correct. I'm just posting this to add some background information, and to vent my frustration at Hewlett-Packard for creating this stupid situation.

If you buy a Hewlett-Packard PC with Windows pre-installed (which is typical, unless you're in the IT dept. of a company that wipes the hard disk and installs a preconfigured disk image) then Hewlett-Packard has stupidly installed Windows with their name as the owner and owning organization.

Here are some links. I'm surprised there aren't even more frustrated customers complaining about this.

https://www.besttechie.com/forums/topic/11774-change-the-name-of-the-registered-owner-on-an-oem-machine/

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/change-the-registered-owner-and-company-name-in-windows/
- see the comments

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/12fdb09b-472b-4634-991c-670e5f775365/upon-new-project-hewlettpackard-is-always-placed-in-the-assembly-company-name-field?forum=visualstudiogeneral

https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/bph05548
- is obsolete, doesn't include x64 registry entry

So the solution is to do this, **as soon as you power up the new HP machine** (otherwise this owner information will "pollute" all the programs you install):

1. Fix the RegisteredOrganization and RegisteredOwner registry information at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
2. If it's an x64 machine (and all machines are now), also fix the RegisteredOrganization and RegisteredOwner registry information at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine you're looking for the [AssemblyInfo.Copyright](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.assemblyinfo.copyright.aspx) Property.  In order to modify this simply find the assembly.info class and modify it appropriately.

If you can't find it you can also use the [Assembly Information Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h52t681%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as suggested by @Louis, which modifies the file for you.